# how to append file content in velocity in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I am trying to write a simple sample :) on Apache-camel velocity. It is supposed to pick up a file and insert its content in a pre-written text (in .vm file). But it just puts the file name in the place. Here is my scripts.

blueprint.xml

```
    <camelContext id="_context1" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route id="_route1">
        <from id="_from1" uri="file:work/velocityFileInput"/>
        <setHeader headerName="receiver" id="_setHeader1">
            <simple>sir</simple>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="senderName" id="_setHeader1">
            <simple>Magfa co.</simple>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="meetingAddress" id="_setHeader1">
            <simple> Tehran , Iran</simple>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="senderPersonalName" id="_setHeader1">
            <simple>Ehsan Zangeneh</simple>
        </setHeader>          
        <to id="_to1" uri="velocity:email.vm"/>
        <log message="${body}"></log>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

and here is my .vm file content

```js
Hello dear ${headers.receiver},
This letter is sent from ${headers.senderName} to inform you that you are
invited to the meeting in the address of '${headers.meetingAddress}'.
The meeting is about
${in}
Best regards
${headers.senderPersonalName}
```

instead of ${in}, I also tried ${body} which didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert the body to string after retrieving content **from URI** the file.

Might this work, Your route will be like this

```
<route id="_route1">
 <from id="_from1" uri="file:work/velocityFileInput"/>
 <convertBodyTo id="_convertBodyFileContent" type="java.lang.String"/>
 <setHeader headerName="receiver" id="_setHeader1">
  <simple>sir</simple>
 </setHeader>
 <setHeader headerName="senderName" id="_setHeader1">
  <simple>Magfa co.</simple>
 </setHeader>
 <setHeader headerName="meetingAddress" id="_setHeader1">
   <simple> Tehran , Iran</simple>
 </setHeader>
 <setHeader headerName="senderPersonalName" id="_setHeader1">
  <simple>Ehsan Zangeneh</simple>
 </setHeader>          
 <to id="_to1" uri="velocity:email.vm"/>
 <log message="${body}"></log>
</route>
```

and here is your .vm file content

```
Hello dear ${headers.receiver},
This letter is sent from ${headers.senderName} to inform you that you are
invited to the meeting in the address of '${headers.meetingAddress}'.
The meeting is about
${body}
Best regards
${headers.senderPersonalName}
```